# Problems with Grub2 and multiple installations

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a machine with Windows 7 and Scientific Linux 6 running as a dual boot. This distribution of Linux used legacy Grub.

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 by specifying a desired partition, so as not to over-write my SL6 installation. I know that SL6 is a on `/dev/sda5` and I know its UUID.

I've tried following tutorials to add entries to the boot menu. I can add entries, but selecting them invariably gives me error messages:

```
error: file not found
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

I've become very roughly acquainted with Grub2 over the last few hours, and I was hoping for any input as to how to get my SL6 distribution on `/dev/sda5` to be recognized and bootable with grub2. I've files on that distribution which I need to get at in the next few days.

I've run the 'boot-repair' utility that has been recommended. I created an initial diagnostic file before doing anything to grub, you can find it [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5709327/) and then, after running the suggested repair routine, here is another diagnostic [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5709361/).

Clearly, it can recognize that `/dev/sda5` is there, and it can sense some of the old boot-related files that SL6 was using with legacy grub.

I'm willing to learn and do other steps/diagnostics to get this running, but can someone please let me know how to go about getting SL6 on `/dev/sda5` to boot?

Comment: <pre>#!/bin/sh -e
echo "hope for SL 6"
cat << EOF
menuentry "SL6" {
set root=(hd0,5)
linux /vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_chamber-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_LVM_LV=vg_chamber/lv_swap rd_NO_MD quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb crashkernel=128M rd_LVM_LV=vg_chamber/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64.img
}
EOF </pre>

Also, here is a copy of my script file from /etc/grub.d/, which I'm using to add the new grub2 entry I want:

Comment: No luck with your suggestion NikTh. I think the problem may be in the actual script I am using (in /etc/grub.d ), but I can't find a nice way to post it for reading. I had to resort to dumping it in the comment above. Most of the mess is extra options for the kernel line.

Comment: You can edit you question and add the additional info inside Code Sample <$> .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to first mount the partition /dev/sda5 and then run an update-grub ?

Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and run

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt 
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Just to clarify. I've tried the above suggestion without any avail. It still seems to fail in finding the kernel. I can mount /dev/sda5 to /mnt. I can see that it has the kernel and initramfs files mentioned in the diagnoistic script, and the ones which were used to originally boot this Scientific Linux on sda5. 

I know that /dev/sda has grub2 installed to it. I'm pretty sure I've left /dev/sda5 as it was before. 

What is the significance of chroot'ing a mounted partition. It seems people to do this to install grub to a specific partition. Is that what I want/need to do here?

Comment: Also, I can't even chroot the mounted /dev/sda5 because it's lacking basic folders/utilities like bash. If I try to chroot the mounted /dev/sda5 on /mnt, I get an error saying bash failed because there is no /bin/bash folder in /dev/sda5 (I have check there is not).